# jQuery: Multiple Checkbox Select and price determination

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to create a "digital breakfast/lunch/dinner list", where over the space of 2 weeks parents can select whether or not their child needs to have breakfast, lunch and/or dinner.  These values will be multiplied against different rates for each meal to determine an invoice amount.  The parent clicks a submission button which returns the total value. Here's what I've got so far:

Web Form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="breakfast">
<input type="checkbox" name="lunch">
<input type="checkbox" name="dinner">
```

There are 14 days, with this repeated for each.  So in total I have 42 checkboxes.

jQuery:

```
var numBreakfast = $("input:checkbox[name='breakfast']").size();
var numLunch = $("input:checkbox[name='lunch']").size();
var numDinner = $("input:checkbox[name='dinner']").size();

var totalPrice = numBreakfast * priceBreakfast + numLunch * priceLunch + numDinner * priceDinner
```

I think I've got this correct, but when I call the total I keep getting $0.00 returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: .size() will only tell you how many you have not how many are checked

Comment: `size` is deprecated use `length` instead

Comment: your code should not give you zero unless the prices are zero, or you run code before elements exist. Should show more of your code. Doesn't mean your code is correct regarding checked but zero shoudn't be happening

Comment: this demo shows your code does work as is (without considering checked) http://jsfiddle.net/jVADp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to actually count how many items were checked:

```
var numBreakfast = $('input:checkbox[name=breakfast]:checked').length;
// same with all the others
```

Note the use of `length` instead of `size()` since the later has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculate(){
var numBreakfast = $("input:checkbox[name='breakfast']"),numBreakfastCount=0
numLunch = $("input:checkbox[name='lunch']"), numLunchCount=0;
numDinner = $("input:checkbox[name='dinner']"),numDinnerCount=0,
priceDinner=2.00,priceLunch=3.00,priceBreakfast=5.00;

for(i=0;i<numBreakfast.length;i++){
    if(numBreakfast[i].checked == true){
        numBreakfastCount++
    }
}

for(i=0;i<numLunch.length;i++){
    if(numLunch[i].checked == true){
        numLunchCount++
    }
}

for(i=0;i<numDinner.length;i++){
    if(numDinner[i].checked == true){
        numDinnerCount++
    }
}

var totalPrice = (numBreakfastCount * priceBreakfast) + (numLunchCount * priceLunch) + (numDinnerCount * priceDinner);
console.log(totalPrice);
}
```

Comment: you might also think about adding a class name to each input and instead of this $("input:checkbox[name='breakfast']")  do $(".breakfast")

Comment: This code doesn't look particularly great... You're missing semicolons, `i` is global, `== true` would typically be omitted in JS, plus OP is using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use `length` and not `size`.

`$('input:checkbox[name="breakfast"]:checked').length` will give you the count of checked 'breakfast' boxes.

Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/5qymM/1/